# ElGamal import a big prime number

Tags: java, bouncycastle, elgamal

I recently implement multiple cryptographic schemes. I plan to use Java Bouncy Castle. I found importing the scheme is very easy. My first implementation is the ElGamal encryption.
My question is that how to import my generated Big prime number p and order q and use these parameters to generate the key pairs with Bouncy castle.

I found when I use the Bouncy Castle, I can import the name of the scheme and 'BC'. For example, Elgamal encryption.

KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ElGamal", "BC");

My question is that how can I get the generator g, order q, and big prime number p from this because other schemes need these parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't 'get' the field parameters, you provide them. Note you only need p and g; although the generator g does (must) *have* a large prime order q in Z_p^* the ElGamal implementation doesn't use or need that order.

`KeyPairGenerator.init` with either Bouncy's [`ElGamalParameterSpec`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/ElGamalParameterSpec.java) or JCA's [`DHParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/spec/DHParameterSpec.html). JCA doesn't define classes (or algorithms) for ElGamal, but the mathematical fields used are the same as for Diffie-Hellman which it does define, so Bouncy allows you to 'repurpose' the DH classes. (Like Rocky on PAW Patrol: don't lose it, reuse it!)

Comment: Really, thanks. I basically understand your answers. Many thanks.